# generating a string with specific rules

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to generate a string with the length of seven characters and the below are the following rules.

The string  will contain 7 characters and will be randomly generated:

- First character will be between A-E
- Second character will be between 1-5
- Third character will be between 0
- Fourth character will be between e-m
- Fifth character will be between $/^/_
- Sixth character will be between K-S
- Seventh character will be between 6-9

Can anyone please help me how can I do that thing in Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample. It is just a quick and dirty way. You can expand it for 7 letters.

```
    NSArray *firstLetter = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e", nil];
    NSArray *secondLetter = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];

    NSArray *letters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstLetter,secondLetter, nil];

    NSMutableString *randomString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (NSArray *letter in letters) 
    {
        int randomIndex = arc4random() % [letter count];
        [randomString appendFormat:@"%@",[letter objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];

    }
    NSLog(@"Random String%@",randomString);
```